# How to Find number of unique straight lines in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, line

We have been given a matrix of size M * N and value inside each location of matrix is represented as a Dot.  We have to find number of unique straight lines that can be drawn through 2 or more points.
E.g.
M=2, N=2

```
*   *

*   *
```

Number of unique lines can be drawn is 6.

Similarly like M=2, N=3

```
*    *    *

*    *    *
```

Number of unique lines can be drawn is 11.

I am not able to figure out a way to resolve this problem.Please help.

Comment: If you're just looking for the algorithm, and not a way to actually program it in a specific language, this seems like the type of problem http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/ would actually like.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774824/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-distinctive-uncurving-straight-lines-in-a-matrix-in


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774824/how-do-i-find-the-number-of-distinctive-uncurving-straight-lines-in-a-matrix-in

Answer (score 5):

I figured since such a question is nowhere to be found on Google, it was worth answering. It is certainly an interesting question, but try providing a bit of code yourself next time.

**This is my solution** (Forgive my python being a bit rusty)

```
def notDiagonal(path):
    point1, point2 = path
    a1, a2 = point1
    b1, b2 = point2
    if(a1 == b1):
        return True
    if(a2 == b2):
        return True
    else:
        return False

N, M = 4, 2
matPoints, matPairs, bounds, edges = [], [], [], [(0,0),(N-1,0),(0,M-1),(N-1,M-1)]

def oneEdge(path):
    point1, point2 = path
    if (point1 not in edges and point2 not in edges) or (point1 in edges and point2 in edges):
        return False
    return True

for i in range(N):
    if (i,0) not in bounds:
        bounds.append((i,0))
    if (i,M-1) not in bounds:
        bounds.append((i,M-1))
    for j in range(M):
        matPoints.append((i, j))

for j in range(M):
    if (0,j) not in bounds:
        bounds.append((0,j))
    if (N-1,j) not in bounds:
        bounds.append((N-1,j))        

print("number of points is: ", len(matPoints))

for i in range(len(matPoints)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(matPoints)):
        matPairs.append(  ( matPoints[i], matPoints[j]  )   )
matPairCopy = list(matPairs)

print("number of lines before removal: ", len(matPairs))

for i in range(len(matPairs)):

    a = (matPairs[i][0][0] + matPairs[i][1][0])/2.0
    b = (matPairs[i][0][1] + matPairs[i][1][1])/2.0

    if(int(a) == a and int(b) == b):

            # Center point is (int(a), int(b))
            # Delete the partitioned lines if they exist (they may have been deleted before)

            if(  ((matPairs[i][0][0], matPairs[i][0][1]),   (int(a), int(b))) in matPairCopy):
                matPairCopy.remove(   ((matPairs[i][0][0], matPairs[i][0][1]),   (int(a), int(b)))    )
            if(  ((int(a), int(b))  ,  (matPairs[i][1][0], matPairs[i][1][1])   ) in matPairCopy     ):
                matPairCopy.remove(   ((int(a), int(b))  ,  (matPairs[i][1][0], matPairs[i][1][1])   ))

for k in matPairs:
    if(k[0] not in bounds or k[1] not in bounds):
        if(k in matPairCopy):
            matPairCopy.remove(k)
    elif(notDiagonal(k) and (oneEdge(k)) and k in matPairCopy):
                matPairCopy.remove(k)

print("number of lines after removing partitions: ",  len(matPairCopy))
```

**EDITED: Fixed small issue**

**N = 2, M = 2: Output = 6**

**N = 2, M = 3: Output = 11**

**N = 2, M = 4: Output = 18**

**N = 3, M = 3: Output = 20**

**N = 3, M = 4: Output = 31**

Comment: I tried to run your code but it is not giving correct answer. For M=2, N=2,  'number of points is: ', 4)
'number of lines before removal: ', 6)
'number of lines after removing partitions: ', 1)      , so answer it shows is 1.                               Similarly for M=2, N=3 ,     ('number of points is: ', 6)
('number of lines before removal: ', 15)
('number of lines after removing partitions: ', 5) . Answer it gives is 5 in place of 11.

Comment: I'll try cut some of the code down, but the code is fully functioning now, test again !

Comment: Shouldn't N=2, M=4 give 16 as a result?

Comment: I counted 18, I did 4,2 and 3,3 manually and my program yielded the same results

Comment: Uhm... That's interesting. My point is that if you have a 6 in (2,2), that means that (2,3) doubles that number, minus one line because two lines overlap. So (2,3) = (6+6) -1 = 11.  If you have (2,4), that means that you add another 6 minus one line because other two lines overlap, which means (2,4) = (11+6)-1 = 16. What am I missing here?

Comment: @DennisCallanan . I executed your code and it worked fine. But i have a doubt in a section of your code: -    for k in matPairs:
                if(k[0] not in bounds or k[1] not in bounds):
                    if(k in matPairCopy):
                        matPairCopy.remove(k)
                elif(notDiagonal(k) and (oneEdge(k)) and k in matPairCopy):
                            matPairCopy.remove(k)
Can you please explain the logic behind it ? Why you are doing this?

Comment: I removed some faulty indentation (it might have confused you). Yes, the lines you mentioned are indeed the tricky ones. I'll try to explain. If the line stops within the bounds , it can be extended and hence, should be deleted. Otherwise, if the line lies on the same bound (not diagonal) but does not go from edge to edge, it can also be extended, and hence, should be deleted. Does this make sense?

Comment: The other conditions sort out the rest

Comment: @DennisCallanan . I tried to execute your code in my local online interpreter as well as online interpreter ( http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php ) , it is not giving correct output. But when i am trying to run in your given link, it is working fine. Any reason why ? Can you try once copy and paste your code in the mentioned link and check

Comment: @Neer1009 Clearly it is a change between python 2.7 and 3. Tbh I've always worked with 3 so find it hard locating the issue with 2.7. I'll see if I can determine the problem but for now just run on python 3

Comment: Solved, divided by `2.0` instead of `2`. Change between python versions. Edited.

Comment: Your 3,4 count looks a little low to me. I count 35: 3 horizontal, 4 vertical, 4 with slope 1 and 4 with slope -1, 4 with slope 1/2 and 4 with slope -1/2, 2 with slope 1/3 and 2 with slope -1/3, 3 with slope 2 and 3 with slope -2, 1 with slope 2/3 and 1 with slope -2/3. Total of 3 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 4 + 2 + 2 +3 + 3 + 1 + 1 = 35. I did it both by hand and by computer, but I might be thinking of it incorrectly.

Comment: You may be right, my interpretation may have been incorrect... Ah well, can't say I didn't try, and it might help get other people thinking. I'll see if I can fix that bug at some stage. It is probably a small enough bug

Answer (score 2):

On edit: I added some code to handle degenerate cases where M < 2 and/or N < 2. For testing purposes, I was able to reproduce the first 10 entries of [this](https://oeis.org/A160843) sequence from the On-line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Here is my take: It is trivial to count the number of horizontal and vertical, so concentrate on the other slopes. There is a 1-1 correspondence between lines of (strictly) positive and lines of (strictly) negative slope, so count the positives and multiply by 2. To count the lines with positive slope, I enumerate all possibilities a/b with a,b relatively prime (so the slope is in reduced form). For each line of that slope I call its *control box* the rectangle of height a and width b with the property that it can't grow to a rectangle of dimensions 2*a x 2*b with the same lower left corner while remaining in the grid. In the following not-quite optimal diagram the line is one of slope 1. It passes through 3 points. The control box would be the square it cuts through diagonally on the top row rather than the square it cuts through on the bottom row:

```
*   *   *   *
      /
*   *   *   *
  /     
*   *   *   *
```

I count the number of control boxes for a given a,b by counting the total number of ways to place an axb (first dimension is height) box minus the number of ways to place such a box that are far enough from the upper right hand corner of the grid that they have room to grow. After a bit of algebra (and a lot of debugging) I came up with the following Python 3 code:

```
from fractions import gcd

def distinctLines(m,n):
    if m == 0 or n == 0:
        return 0
    elif m == 1 and n == 1:
        return 0
    elif m == 1 or n ==1:
        return 1
    else:
        numLines = m + n
        slopes = ((a,b) for a in range(1,m) for b in range(1,n) if gcd(a,b) == 1)
        for a,b in slopes:
            numLines += 2*((m-a)*(n-b) - max(m-2*a,0)*max(n-2*b,0))
        return numLines
```

Sample output:

```
>>> for n in range(10): print(distinctLines(3,n), end = ' ')

0 1 11 20 35 52 75 100 131 164
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution, but not necessarily a good one in performance measurements:

Make a list of all pairs of dots `(M*N choose 2)`, and for each pair `(a, b)` check if any other dot `c` is on the same line. If it is, delete `(a, c)` and `(b, c)` from the list.

You're left with all unique lines represented by pairs of dots.

Comment: Can you provide some steps in pseudocode so that i can understand better.

Answer (score 0):

Split the problem up into several parts:

- find all distinct values the pitch of a line can hold: these pitches must lie between `(0 , -1)` (inclusively) and `(0 , 1)` (exclusively) on the unity-circle. Except for `(0 , -1)` and `(1 , 0)` each pitch `(x , y)` has a peer defined as `(x , -y)` that matches the requirements. So basically the set of valid pitches would be
  `{(0,-1),(1,0)} merge D:{da , db|da=(1,y), y=m/n with 0 <= M <`M`and 0 < n <`N`, db=(1 , y(db)}`. Finding the distinct pitches is a bit tough (i'd suggest to simply bruteforce this part).
- find the number of lines for each distinct pitch of the line: the line with pitch `(0 , -1)` can be inserted exactly `M` times, the line with pitch `(1 , 0)` exactly `N` times, for any other line the following applies: let the pitch be `(x , y)` where `x` and `y` are integers. There are `N - x + M - y` lines with this pitch that cover atleast 2 points. Requirements for the list of pitches:

  - every item in the list is unique: for a pitch `p = (x , y)` no pitch `b = (u , v)` such that `x = d * u` and `y = d * v`.
  - every item in the list consists of integers: for any pitch `p = (x , y)`, `x` and `y` must be integers

Sorry for the horrible way of explaining, couldn't find any tool to generate a more mathematical notation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a brute force solution [here](https://gist.github.com/dpmcmlxxvi/0299f96fd4eec23071a3) is a python implementation. Basically, it loops through all pairs of points and only keeps unique lines in normal form. Below is a sample output

```
M =  1    N =  1    Count =  0
M =  1    N =  2    Count =  1
M =  1    N =  3    Count =  1
M =  1    N =  4    Count =  1
M =  1    N =  5    Count =  1
M =  1    N =  6    Count =  1
M =  1    N =  7    Count =  1
M =  1    N =  8    Count =  1
M =  1    N =  9    Count =  1
M =  2    N =  2    Count =  6
M =  2    N =  3    Count =  11
M =  2    N =  4    Count =  18
M =  2    N =  5    Count =  27
M =  2    N =  6    Count =  38
M =  2    N =  7    Count =  51
M =  2    N =  8    Count =  66
M =  2    N =  9    Count =  83
M =  3    N =  3    Count =  20
M =  3    N =  4    Count =  35
M =  3    N =  5    Count =  52
M =  3    N =  6    Count =  75
M =  3    N =  7    Count =  100
M =  3    N =  8    Count =  131
M =  3    N =  9    Count =  164
M =  4    N =  4    Count =  63
M =  4    N =  5    Count =  96
M =  4    N =  6    Count =  141
M =  4    N =  7    Count =  188
M =  4    N =  8    Count =  246
M =  4    N =  9    Count =  309
M =  5    N =  5    Count =  145
M =  5    N =  6    Count =  214
M =  5    N =  7    Count =  282
M =  5    N =  8    Count =  371
M =  5    N =  9    Count =  466
M =  6    N =  6    Count =  314
M =  6    N =  7    Count =  415
M =  6    N =  8    Count =  546
M =  6    N =  9    Count =  687
M =  7    N =  7    Count =  548
M =  7    N =  8    Count =  723
M =  7    N =  9    Count =  910
M =  8    N =  8    Count =  954
M =  8    N =  9    Count =  1201
M =  9    N =  9    Count =  1512
```

**Alternative Approach**

How about using a variant of the [Hough Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) that detects lines. Usually, the Hough Transform uses an accumulator to group lines together into bins of their radius and angle. However, for a fixed M and N you can determine the smallest resolution in both the radius and angle direction so you can get an exact answer.

For example, compute the set of all line radii and angles of all points using the top left point as the origin. These values should be the same for all other points. However, you'll have to also include the correspondent angles in the other three quadrants.

Then, run the Hough Transform using those values for your accumulator bin centers. The bin size will have to be the smallest resolution in the values computed above. Any accumulator bin with a count more than one represents a line with more than one point going through it. Add them up and that is your answer.

Comment: I don't think that your counts are correct after 3,9. For example - compare your output for the square (M = N) case with these numbers: https://oeis.org/A018808. That Hough Transform idea sounds interesting. Hopefully it will work out.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers above:

This is the subject of the paper [On lines and their intersection points in a rectangular grid of points](http://www.survo.fi/papers/PointsInGrid.pdf) by [Seppo Mustonen](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Seppo_Mustonen). I found this by looking up [John Coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4996248/john-coleman)'s output `0 1 11 20 35 52 75 100 131 164` in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences, which pointed me to sequence [A160843](http://oeis.org/A160843).